# Testing Material Ui (v5) Drawer - Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null

Tags: material-ui, mocha.js, enzyme

This is a simple example that shows the problem. (switching to shallow testing isn't an option for real tests). This didn't happen in materialui v4. (only after the upgrade to mui v5)

```
it('Test Drawer', () =>
{
    enzyme.mount(<Drawer  
        open={true}
    >
        <div>hello world</div>
    </Drawer>);        
})
```

yields the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null
    at reflow (node_modules\@mui\material\node\transitions\utils.js:9:29)
    at $SOMEPATH\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Fade\Fade.js:94:24
    at Object.onEnter (node_modules\@mui\material\node\Fade\Fade.js:87:9)
    at Transition.performEnter (node_modules\@mui\material\node_modules\react-transition-group\cjs\Transition.js:283:16)
    at Transition.updateStatus (node_modules\@mui\material\node_modules\react-transition-group\cjs\Transition.js:249:14)
    at Transition.componentDidMount (node_modules\@mui\material\node_modules\react-transition-group\cjs\Transition.js:193:10)
    at commitLifeCycles (node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:20663:24)
    at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:23426:7)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackProd (node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:3862:10)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
```

lib versions

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"@mui/material": "^5.0.4",
"enzyme": "^3.9.0",
"@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.3",
```

Now the v4 -> v5 migraton guide [says](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#cannot-read-property-scrolltop-of-null):

"You need to make sure that the children forward ref to DOM for custom component."

Here is what I've tried

```
        let r = React.createRef();

        enzyme.mount(<Drawer
            ref={r}
            open={true}
        >
            <div>hello world</div>
        </Drawer>);
```

But that makes no difference, and the [documentation](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#TemporaryDrawer.js) examples of `Drawer` doesn't pass a ref.

How can I mount test `Drawer`? This only happens in tests (not when running for real)

**UPDATE:**

Test mounting `Modal` does the same thing:

```
it('test Modal', () =>
{
    const wrapper = enzyme.mount(<Modal open={true}><div>hello</div></Modal>);

    console.log(wrapper.debug());
})
```

and so yield this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null
at reflow (node_modules\@mui\material\node\transitions\utils.js:9:29)
at $SOMEPATH\node_modules\@mui\material\node\Fade\Fade.js:94:24
at Object.onEnter (node_modules\@mui\material\node\Fade\Fade.js:87:9)
at Transition.performEnter (node_modules\@mui\material\node_modules\react-transition-group\cjs\Transition.js:283:16)
at Transition.updateStatus (node_modules\@mui\material\node_modules\react-transition-group\cjs\Transition.js:249:14)
at Transition.componentDidMount (node_modules\@mui\material\node_modules\react-transition-group\cjs\Transition.js:193:10)
at commitLifeCycles (node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:20663:24)
at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:23426:7)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackProd (node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:3862:10)
at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
```

However testing the the inner `Fade` component works without error.

```
it('test Fade', () =>
{
    const wrapper = enzyme.mount(<Fade in={true}><div>hello</div></Fade>);

    console.log(wrapper.debug());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to enclose the content that I want to show inside Fade in a Box with 100vh

```
<Box minHeight="100vh">{children}</Box>
```

Comment: This worked for me after trying different forwardRef techniques suggested elsewhere.  Just wrapping my content in a simple Box. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Workaround - Apply the following props on `Drawer` or any `Modal` based component (eg. `Dialog`) to disable Transitions whilst running tests.

```
const disableTransitionProps = {
        disablePortal: true,
        hideBackdrop: true,
        TransitionComponent: ({ children }) => children
      };


enzyme.mount(<Drawer          
        open={true}
        {...disableTransitionProps }
    >
        <div>hello world</div>
    </Drawer>);
```

**UPDATE**:

I wrapped up the workaround in an react context

```
// ModalProps.Context.jsx
import React from 'react';

const ModalPropsContext = React.createContext({});

// for unittest - workaround MUI c5 (5.0.5) Transitions bugs when runing tests.
export const DefaultForTests = {value : {
                disablePortal : true,
                hideBackdrop: true,
                TransitionComponent: ({ children }) => children
            }}

// For unittests            
export const MountRendererPropsForModalComponents = {wrappingComponent : ModalPropsContext.Provider, wrappingComponentProps : DefaultForTests};

export default ModalPropsContext;
```

One can use it like this:

```
import {MountRendererPropsForModalComponents} from 'ModalPropsContext.jsx'
```

then:

```
const wrapper = enzyme.mount(<SomeComponentThatContainsModalComponents />, MountRendererPropsForModalComponents);
```

Then you just have to import and use the `ModalPropsContext` in components that use `Modal` components.

For example:

```
<Dialog 
   {...this.context}
```

In production code this.context is {} but in test code it returns `disablePortal`, `hideBackdrop` and `TransitionComponent` props needed for the workaround.

For more information about how to use the context see the [react context docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context) - (its different for class and functional components.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on Tom's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69728482/13664939). You can define MUI component default props in the theme. This saves you the effort of having to provide the context to every Modal component.

Create the theme and provide it to the component under test:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { StyledEngineProvider, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import defaultTheme from "../../src/renderer/data/theme";

export default class TestProvider extends React.Component {
  disableTransitions = {
    defaultProps: {
      disablePortal: true,
      hideBackdrop: true,
      TransitionComponent: ({ children }) => children
    }
  };

  render() {
    const theme = createTheme({
      ...defaultTheme,
      // disable Transitions when runing tests, throws errors otherwise.
      components: {
        MuiDialog: this.disableTransitions,
        MuiModal: this.disableTransitions
      }
    } as any);
    return (
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{this.props.children}</ThemeProvider>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Then wrap the component you want to test with `<TestProvider>`:

```js
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

const component = renderer.create(
    <TestProvider>
        <MyTestComponent/>
    </TestProvider>
);
```